# Where do MediaTemple (dv) vhosts configuration files live?

Tags: svn, apache, virtualhost, vhosts, mediatemple

This question is specific to MediaTemple Dedicated-Virtual servers.

When I add a new vhost through the Plesk Panel, where is the vhost configuration saved? There is no /etc/httpd/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf and there is nothing in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/conf/

I am trying to set up a subdomain as a subversion server, tips appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears they are located, for some reason, in

/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/conf/httpd.include

Comment: This has appears to have been changed to `/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/conf/vhosts.conf`

Comment: This is for Plesk-based DV only.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Apache conf file on a Media Temple dv server @:

```
$ /etc/httpd/conf
```

You can go there with:

```
$ cd /etc/httpd/conf
```

You can open it in vim with:

```
$ vim /etc/httpd/conf
```